# unable to connect selenium webDriver through perl bindings

Tags: perl

I have written a simple Perl script to launch google. But it terminates with an error - Could not connect to SeleniumWebDriver at /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/Selenium/Remote/Driver.pm line 220.

i am using selenium server : 2.39.0 jar

OS : ubuntu (32 bit)

`use warnings;

 use strict;

 use Selenium::Remote::Driver;

 my $driver = Selenium::Remote::Driver->new;
 $driver->get('http://www.google.com');`

is perl binding with selenium  will support for ubuntu ?

please can anybody help me about this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: By default it will try to use firefox. What is the command you're using to start selenium and do you have an X session running on your ubuntu box that selenium can use?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium perl bindings works fine with ubuntu. I think problem is with server. its an old one . Pls download latest version v.44 from here http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Make sure you are taking right steps.
1- open a command prompt and run the server
java -jar server_name.jar

2-After successful start up of server. Open Another tab in command prompt and 
run your script
perl -w name.pl